# command line data curl convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I have a curl cammand but i dont know if i have a correct code for data that i convert it to array. I dont have a problem with curl code, I had already tested my curl cammand but i just want to clarify if i have a correct syntax about data.

command line

```
curl - v 
- H "Accept: application/json" 
- H "Content-type: application/json" 
- X POST 
- d '{"cart" : 
    {"cancel_url":"http://yourdomain.com/your_cancel_url",
        "invoice":"11111111",
        "notes":"sample note",
        "success_url":"http://yourdomain.com/your_success_url",
        "total_amount":"30.0",
        "total_quantity":"12.0",
        "items_attributes":
            [
                {"item_code":"111111111-aaa",
                "item_name":"aaaaaaaa",
                "notes": "test item note",
                "price":"2.5", 
                "quantity":"12.0", 
                "amount":"30.0"}
             ]
       }
    }'
```

and here's the data command line that i convert to array and i add more item.
See the command line of "items_attributes" there is `[]`. `[]` this means the client can add multiple items right?

```
$data = array(
    'cart' => array(
        'cancel_url' => "www.google.com",
        'invoice' => '1111111',
        'notes' => 'hello world',
        'success_url' => "www.yahoo.com",
        'total_amount' => 20.00,
        'total_quantity' => 2,
        'item_attributes' => array( 
            array(
                'item_code' => "11111-aaa",
                'item_name' => 'bogart',
                'notes' => 'first notes',
                'price' => 15.2,
                'quantity' => 2,
                'amount' => 20.00
            ),
             array(
                'item_code' => "11111-aaa",
                'item_name' => 'bogart2',
                'notes' => 'second notes',
                'price' => 15.2,
                'quantity' => 2,
                'amount' => 20.00
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Im new in curl. please help me.

Comment: Yes, that means it can have multiple values.  Is that your only question?

Comment: @dan yes! thanks man. I tried to read the tutorial but i cant find any exact resources for it.

Comment: Do you like this
"items_attributes":
            [
                {"item_code":"111111111-aaa",
                "item_name":"aaaaaaaa",
                "notes": "test item note",
                "price":"2.5", 
                "quantity":"12.0", 
                "amount":"30.0"},
                {"item_code":"111111111-aaa",
                "item_name":"aaaaaaaa",
                "notes": "test item note",
                "price":"2.5", 
                "quantity":"12.0", 
                "amount":"30.0"} 
             ]

Comment: @SamarHaider No. what i mean is that do i have a right syntax of my data? if ever i add more items in my item_attributes.

Comment: for adding more item_attributes
$data['cart']['item_attributes'][]=array(
                'item_code' => "11111-aaa",
                'item_name' => 'bogart2',
                'notes' => 'second notes',
                'price' => 15.2,
                'quantity' => 2,
                'amount' => 20.00
            );

Comment: ok man i get it now. thanks. I try your work, it really work. :) how i wish i can upvote ur comment but i have low reputation.